# MySQL fulltext index ngram parser performance

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, n-gram

I'm writing a search utilizing MySQL's fulltext index.

n-gram is 2, and I use InnoDB

I wrote the code as below.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM CAT
WHERE MATCH(CAT.NAME2) AGAINST('${input}' in boolean mode)
```

If I input 'bu', the speed is 0.049s and the number of results is 20,000.

If I type 'but', the speed is 0.641s and the number of results is 160,000.

If I type 'butt', the speed is 0.794s and the number of results is 130,000.

If I input 'butte', the speed is 0.964s and the number of results is 160,000.

...

The longer the input, the slower it will continue to be regardless of the number of results.

As the input's length increases,  it slower regardless of the number of results.

In this case, like '%%' is much faster if the length is longer. like '%butte%' is 0.013s.

I know fulltext index is faster than like. I wonder why this is happening. Would I be better off using like?

I will not limit the length of input.

Also, inserts occur frequently in the cat table.

Would I be better off using like?

I have already run the 'OPTIMIZE TABLE' command.

My previous question was about a combination of multiple fulltext indexes. Please understand that this is not the same question.

ps) There are no additional conditions, and there are about 500,000 data in the cat table.

ps2) I don't just want to find names that start with {input}, I want to search all names that contain it.

ps3) When the 'show create table cat' command is executed, the following is displayed. Does this have any effect?

```
FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_7c4a822bb2837c94c31` (`NAME2`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */ ,
```

ps4) In the case of other tables, it shows the same create statement even though it has more data, and it is slightly slower as the length increases, but it is not as badly slow as the cat table.

```
SELECT *
FROM DOCTOR
WHERE MATCH(DOCTOR.NAME) AGAINST('${input}' in boolean mode)
```

ps5) Spaces have not been considered yet, and if the performance is stabilized, it will be used in the form of '+"xx" +"yy"'.

Comment: How many rows in the table?  Is there some reason to use NGRAM instead of regular FULLTEXT?

Comment: Table has about 500,000 rows. The reason for using ngram is that the data contains Korean, Chinese, Russian, etc.

Comment: NGram is not a commonly used feature in MySQL.  Suggest reporting it as a bug at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll ask mysql.